# Jquery wrapper method not working with window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am puzzled…

Let

```
function myFunction ()
{
    windowOne = window.open('', "_blank", "toolbar=0, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=50,left=150");
    $("<div id='textZone' contenteditable='true' style='background-color:navajowhite; color: red; height: 40px; width:140px;'></div>").appendTo(windowOne.document.body);
    $('#textZone').html('Hurray');
}
```

The html setting of `textZone` is inoperative, while inserting html text between opening and closing `<div>` tags like so *is*:

```
function myFunction ()
{
    windowOne = window.open('', "_blank", "toolbar=0, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=50,left=150");
    $("<div id='textZone' contenteditable='true' style='background-color:navajowhite; color: red; height: 40px; width:140px;'>Hurray</div>").appendTo(windowOne.document.body);
}
```

Can someone explain why?

Edit – I have tried so far:

```
windowOne.focus();
$('#textZone').html('Hurray');
```

and also:

```
$('body#textZone').html('Hurray');
```

and also:

```
$('windowOne.document.body').html('Hurray');
```

and so on and so forth.

N.B.: I might have to turn 'Hurray' into 'Crumbs'…

Comment: `$('#textZone')` is looking for the selector in the current window. You need to make it look within the new window. I'm not sure of the best way to do that in your use case but hopefully this gives you an idea.

Comment: @rdubya — You must be right and I tend to agree, but… nothing doing, so far.

Answer (score 1):

As @rdubya said you need to specify that you seaching element in other document, otherwise it will search element in main window.

Try this:

```
$( '#textZone', windowOne.document.body ).html( 'Hurray' )
```

Comment: You are right, it works, thank you. I find your solution most efficient because it remains within jQuery framework. Is there any means we can get directly in touch about a job opportunity?

Comment: The following can be of interest: _windowOne.document.body_  can be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jy68hm6L/)

You essentially need to write your new elements markup to a reference of the new window.

- Define a reference to your "popup".
- Store a reference to the HTML
  that will exist in your popup.
- Call your popups reference and write your stored HTML to that popup.

---

```
function myFunction() {
  var newWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "toolbar=0, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=50,left=150");
  var newElement = "<div id='textZone' contenteditable='true' style='background-color:navajowhite; color: red; height: 40px; width:140px;'>Hurray</div>";

  newWindow.document.write(newElement);
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, since you left _Hurray_ between the <div> opening and closing tags… Altogether your piece of code has the same output as mine (see original post, code citation 2). Is there something I am missing? Please also take a look at Arnial's answer.